# Auto-Authenticating Users with Refresh Token but Inactive Session Google OAuth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, passport.js

Is it possible to authenticate a user using Google OAuth without forcing the user to choose allow / deny (ie. is it possible to "auto-authenticate") when I already have the user's refresh token, but their session with the application is no longer active?

Such as:

- The user is using a different computer
- The user is using a different browser on the same computer
- The user's computer is re-imaged on every restart / cookies cleared on restart
- Our session cookie expired

Note that I've set approval_prompt=force since I need the refresh token. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you want to do... no user interaction is required to use a refresh token to get a new refresh token for whatever the scopes were.  But a refresh token can’t be used to verify user presence, its whole point is to do this stuff when the user is absent.

If what you need to do is test that the user is *present*, you have to go through some sort of authentication interaction, with one exception. If you know the email address and do an OpenID Connect login with a scope like "openid email" and you send the email that you know about along using the login_hint parameter, then if that email user is present and signed in, your operation will succeed with no interaction required.  Some useful details are at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer